# How to upload jar to respository?

Tags: java, maven-2, jar, maven

I have jar files that cannot be found on Maven Central repository. I would like to add the jar so I can just include extra  tag in my `pom.xml` file and other developer can use the jar. What are the steps needed to upload the jar to http webserver webfolder? What file should I uploaded beside `custom.jar`? What other files need to exist on the webfolder side by side with `custom.jar`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you already have a web server set up pointing on a web folder, a simple way to deploy your custom JAR would to use the [`deploy:deploy-file`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) Mojo. As documented in the [Usage](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html) page of the Maven Deploy Plugin:

> The `deploy:deploy-file` mojo is used
>   primarily for deploying artifacts to
>   which were not built by Maven. The
>   project's development team may or may
>   not provide a POM for the artifact,
>   and in some cases you may want to
>   deploy the artifact to an internal
>   remote repository. The deploy-file
>   mojo provides functionality covering
>   all of these use cases, and offers a
>   wide range of configurability for
>   generating a POM on-the-fly.
>   Additionally, you can specify what
>   layout your repository uses. The full
>   usage statement of the deploy-file
>   mojo can be described as:
>
> ```
> mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=file://C:\m2-repo \
>                        -DrepositoryId=some.id \
>                        -Dfile=your-artifact-1.0.jar \
>                        [-DpomFile=your-pom.xml] \
>                        [-DgroupId=org.some.group] \
>                        [-DartifactId=your-artifact] \
>                        [-Dversion=1.0] \
>                        [-Dpackaging=jar] \
>                        [-Dclassifier=test] \
>                        [-DgeneratePom=true] \
>                        [-DgeneratePom.description="My Project Description"] \
>                        [-DrepositoryLayout=legacy] \
>                        [-DuniqueVersion=false]
> ```

Only the 3 first parameters are mandatory (short version). If you wonder what the [repositoryId](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html#repositoryId) is, the documentation of the Mojo says:

> Server Id to map on the `<id>` under `<server>` section of `settings.xml` In most cases, this parameter will be required for authentication. Default value is: remote-repository.

In other words, the simplest way to use this would be to copy your custom JAR on the machine hosting the web server and to use the `file://` protocol when specifying the URL. There is no additional setup required. If you want to deploy remotely, then `scp://` is often the preferred protocol (there are others but this one is pretty easy to setup). Below, an example using scp:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=my.group -DartifactId=myartifact -Dversion=1.0 \
  -DgeneratePom=true \
  -Dpackaging=jar \
  -Dfile=custom.jar \
  -DrepositoryId=some.id \
  -Durl=scp://REMOTEMACHINE/PATH/TO/WEB_ROOT/maven2_repository
```

Actually, using a web server to host your own Maven repository is perfectly fine but it can be a bit painful to initialize. One solution to solve this issue is to use a Maven proxy (like [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) for example) instead of just a Maven repository. But this goes beyond your question.

For more resources on this, check (the principles are still valid even if the implementation solutions are a bit outdated):

- [Using Maven in a corporate environment](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Using+Maven+in+a+corporate+environment#UsingMaveninacorporateenvironment-internalrepository)
- [Creating the repositories](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Creating+the+repositories)
- [Nexus Book: Repository Management with Nexus](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/)

Answer (score 1):

Preferably, you would need a local maven repository. One option for this is [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/)

Or if you are working just yourself, you can save the overhead and put the jars in the repository on your machine - under `home/.m2/repository`, in an appropriate folder

Comment: if i want to upload to http server, web folder,what other files do i need to include on the same folder with custom.jar? can provide steps?

Comment: well, I can google some tutorial on the matter. But it's preferable that you do it. I gave you a link which has plenty of information.

Answer (score 1):

Next command helps to install the jar to the local repository. After this you can upload folder with the jar from local to the remote repository.

```
mvn install:install-file \
  -DgroupId=com.name \
  -DartifactId=aaaa-bc \
  -Dversion=1.0 \
  -Dpackaging=jar \
  -Dfile=aaaa-bc.jar \
  -DcreateChecksum=true
```

Comment: i want to put in remote respository not install on local repository